# Serverless Function exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb

Tags: python, flask, deployment, vercel, aws-serverless

I'm trying to deploy a Flask REST API on Vercel, and in my latest commit, I'm running into this error during deployment:

```
Installing required dependencies...
Build Completed in /vercel/output [48s]
Failed to process build result for "index.py". Data: {"type":"Lambda"}.
Error: The Serverless Function "index.py" is 79.31mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb. Learn More: https://vercel.link/serverless-function-size
```

I know that it's probably my dependencies, listed here:

```
Flask==2.1.3
nlpcloud==1.0.29
python-dotenv==0.20.0
supabase==0.5.8
pyjwt==2.4.0
PyDrive2==1.14.0
Flask_Cors==3.0.10
openai==0.23.0
Flask_Limiter==2.6.2
```

For reference, here are my vercel.json and index.py files:

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./index.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address
from endpoints.database_endpoints import database 
from endpoints.model_endpoints import model
from endpoints.workspace_endpoints import workspace


# Flask setup
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(database, url_prefix="")
app.register_blueprint(model, url_prefix="")
app.register_blueprint(workspace, url_prefix="")
cors = CORS(app)

# Add limiter for OpenAI (max 60 requests per minute)
limiter = Limiter(app, key_func=get_remote_address, storage_uri="memory://")
limiter.limit("60/minute")(model)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "<h1>Endpoint is up and running</h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I was just wondering if there was any possible workaround for this issue in Python? I've seen some online comments suggest excluding the /public folder, but since this isn't a front end app, I don't think that applies. What are my options?

Comment: Update: I checked my dependencies to see what the issue was, and it seems to be the OpenAI library being too large. Prior to adding it, the deployment worked fine, but OpenAI seems to be at least 26MB.

Comment: How do you check the size of these libraries?

Comment: @Kebby you can use `du -hs` in the env directory where your libraries were installed after you ran `pip install -r requirements.txt`.